# Error related to scriptDatabaseOptions when generating scwdp using Azure Toolkit

Tags: packages, azure-toolkit

**Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.7.0 and 2.8.0**

Trying to convert a module package into an scwdp package using the following command:

```
$package = "C:\temp\MyModulePackage.zip"
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path $package  -Destination $destination -DisableDacPacOptions * -Force
```

> Provider 'dbDacFx' does not support setting 'scriptDatabaseOptions'.

If I remove the parameter `DisableDacPacOptions` then it complains:

> ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage : The SQL provider cannot run with dacpac option because of a missing dependency.
> Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more at:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.

What could be the possible cause for the `scriptDatabaseOptions` error?

Comment: I did notice that on Sitecore documentation (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sat/28/sitecore-azure-toolkit/web-deploy-packages-for-a-module.html) * character is wrapped in single quotes like -DisableDacPacOptions '*'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce both errors as you mentioned with my local environment using `Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.7.0`.

[image]

As part of Prerequisites while using Sitecore Azure Toolkit, It require to install `Data-Tier Application Framework` (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sat/27/sitecore-azure-toolkit/getting-started-with-the-sitecore-azure-toolkit.html)

**It gets resolved by following steps:**

1. I installed [Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55713) (DacFX) for SQL server 2012 or later.
2. Restart the system after installation.

Any of this command works perfectly fine.

`ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path $package  -Destination $destination -DisableDacPacOptions * -Force`

`ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path $package  -Destination $destination -Force`

Hope it helps!